# Make a tile graph in R but with a color key for each column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe composed of 4 categorical variables and 100 observations and would like to plot them as column tiles with colors corresponding to the levels of each variable. How could I do that?

Here is an example data frame:

```
df3=data.frame(
           var1=rep(c(1,2),length(LETTERS)),
           var2=rep(c(1,2,3),length(LETTERS)),
           var3=rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),length(LETTERS)))
```

In theory, I think I should get values of vars 1-3 assigned each one to a row (letter) and column coordinates. Then, use ggplot2 to plot the tile graph like this:

```
d = data.frame(row = factor(c(row(df3))),
           column = factor(c(col(df3))),
           value = c(as.matrix(df3)))
```

ggplot(d,aes(x=column,y=row,fill=value))+geom_tile()

However,apart of not being sure if i created these coordinates well, I also do not see how to have an independent color key for each original df3's column, in the tile graph.

Comment: FYI, you define `df3` and then assign row names to `df`; had you used `df3`, you would error with `invalid 'row.names' length`, because your `df3` has 156 rows. Please refine your sample data.

Comment: As to your *"independent color key"*, basic `ggplot2` supports *one* colour scale per plot; if you want to separate them, then you can use a package like `ggnewscale` to define different color scales, but it may be a bit of work to apply it to the tiling you want.

Comment: Thanks, I do not need to use ggplot2. I was guessing there should be a way to simply plot colors by coordinates in a square...

Comment: Plotting colors in squares is easy, and `ggplot2` does it just fine. But `ggplot2` has rather direct expectations on *legends*, and having a different color legend/scale for each row or column is not within its scope.

Comment: Is it really that easy? How would that be?

Comment: Agus, the comments signals that it is not clear what you look for. If you aim for a "discrete" colour coding, set `fill = as.factor(value)`. This will show a legend of "discrete" colours "per value". If you want to have a colour per column per value, you can create such a colour code by combing your column "number" with the value and turn this into a factor (or character). Obviously, with 4 columns and multiple values, this will result in many "colours". If all breaks down, make a small example with 2 variables and tell us why `geom_tile()` is not producing what you are looking for.